# The method getText() is undifined for the type Button

Tags: java, string, button, methods, undefined

**I am trying to create the simple calculator in eclipse ide and at the time to set the action to the buttons I m facing this problem**

```
    Button btn7 = new Button("7");
    btn7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
    btn7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        String EnterNumber = btn7.getText();
            txtDisplay.setText(EnterNumber);
        }
    });
```

I am facing problem in line no. 5, it is showing their that 'The method getText() is undefined for the type button'

Comment: What `Button` are you using?

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say sorry

Comment: you really should learn about the import statements and what do they mean in Java.  Kind of like alphabet in Java really https://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php

Comment: Where does your Button class come from? Is it the Button class from AWT or do you mean JButton from Swing or is this a JavaFX button? If you don't explain the problem clearly, you won't get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` not to be confused with `JButton`. You might be looking for `getLabel()`?

```
String EnterNumber = btn7.getLabel();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#getLabel()

`JButton` inherits a method called `getText()`, perhaps you have confused the two types of buttons? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

Comment: no no i m looking for button only, actually I m making simple calculator and in that I want to set action for the button that ' if I click on that button number 7 should be printed in textField'

Comment: I'm just saying, where are you finding this `Button`? What did you import to use the `Button`? If it is the one from the first link, it does not have a `getText()` method.

Comment: If you can produce a minimal example that might be helpful, _including_ the imports you are making https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: no no i m looking for button only, actually I m making simple calculator and in that I want to set action for the button that ' if I click on that button then number 7 should be printed in textField'

Comment: Did you just copy paste your original comment on this thread in response to my previous comment, lol

Comment: you where right was confused in Jbutton and button!!! now I understood my mistake Thank you

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if your issue is resolved.